# Firefox - How to simulate trigger keypress

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to simulate keypress using trigger. I create my own extension for Mozilla Firefox. Here is my javascript code:

```
var obj = $("#description-frame").contents().find('body').get(0);
var pressEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
pressEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 20, 0);
obj.dispatchEvent(pressEvent);
```

and HTML code:

```
<iframe id="description-frame" class="error" frameborder="0">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="rte">
Here is example text
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

But it doesn't work fine and I think - this is not problem with iframe, because I tested this code also on input fields and it doesn't work too.
I think, maybe browser (Firefox) block these actions but as we can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events this should be possible. Can anyone tell me where is a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use initKeyboardEvent instead of initKeyEvent as indicated in the documentation

> event.initKeyEvent (Gecko-specific, the DOM 3 event specification in development, use initKeyboardEvent instead)
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent (translated)

```
  var obj = $("#description-frame").contents().find('body').get(0);
  var pressEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  pressEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 20, 0);
  obj.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    console.log('Trigger');
  });
  obj.dispatchEvent(pressEvent);
```